# Shape of biases in Transformer's Feedforward Network

Tags: neural-network

In transformer network ([Vaswani et al., 2017](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.03762)), the feedforward networks have equation:

$\mathrm{FNN}(x) = \max(0, xW_1 + b_1) W_2 + b_2$

where $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times d_\mathrm{model}}$, $W_1 \in\mathbb{R}^{d_\mathrm{model} \times d_{ff}}$, $W_2 \in\mathbb{R}^{d_{ff} \times d_\mathrm{model}}$. We know that the biases $b_1$ and $b_2$ are vectors. But, for the equation to work the shape of $b_1$ and $b_2$ must agree, i.e., $b_1 \in\mathbb{R}^{n \times d_{ff}}$ and $b_2 \in\mathbb{R}^{n \times d_\mathrm{model}}$. My question: is it true that

$b_1 = \begin{bmatrix} (b_1)_{1} & (b_1)_{2} & \dots & (b_1)_{d_{ff}}\\ (b_1)_{1} & (b_1)_{2} & \dots & (b_1)_{d_{ff}} \\ \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots \\ (b_1)_{1} & (b_1)_{2} & \dots & (b_1)_{d_{ff}} \end{bmatrix}$
and
$b_2 = \begin{bmatrix} (b_2)_{1} & (b_2)_{2} & \dots & (b_2)_{d_\mathrm{model}}\\ (b_2)_{1} & (b_2)_{2} & \dots & (b_2)_{d_\mathrm{model}} \\ \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots \\ (b_2)_{1} & (b_2)_{2} & \dots & (b_2)_{d_\mathrm{model}} \end{bmatrix}$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, yes and no.

This is a **position-wise** feed-forward network. $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times d_{model}}$, where $n$ is the sequence length. When we apply the matrix multiplication and bias additions, we do so for each individual position. Therefore, the actual multiplication is a vector of dimensionality $1\times d_{model}$ by the $W_1$ matrix.

In actual implementation terms, we obtain the result for the $n$ vectors with a single matrix multiplication. The bias is a single vector that is **broadcasted** in the addition operation. Broadcasting was introduced by numpy and then adopted by deep learning frameworks. [It is defined](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) as:

> The term broadcasting describes how NumPy treats arrays with different shapes during arithmetic operations. Subject to certain constraints, the smaller array is “broadcast” across the larger array so that they have compatible shapes. Broadcasting provides a means of vectorizing array operations so that looping occurs in C instead of Python. It does this without making needless copies of data and usually leads to efficient algorithm implementations.

In this case, broadcasting is equivalent to repeating the bias vector $n$ times.

This does not mean that the actual vector is $n \times d_{ff}$, but that we apply the addition to each of the $n$ positions.

Comment: Thank you. But to be clear, for example for the first linear layer, is each position multiplied by the same $W_1$ matrix and added the same $b_1$ vector? Or is there a $W_1$ matrix and a $b_1$ vector for each position so that there will be $n$ matrices $W_1$ and $n$ vectors $b_1$ in total?

Comment: Same $W_1$ and $b_1$ for each position.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. The first matrix W1 is shape [d_model,dff] so it transforms the input vector [1 x d_model] to a vector of size [1 x dff]. So the first bias vector is [1 x dff]. The second matrix W2 is going in the opposite direction so it is shape [dff,d_model], it takes an input shape [1 x dff] and produces an output [1 x d_model] so the second bias should be a vector of shape [1 x d_model]. The biases b1 and b2 are just vectors (ignoring batching). hth.